# Lotus Notes 7 - When it's composed, the form position isn't central

Tags: position, lotus-notes, lotus-formula

I compose a form from a view action : `@Command([Compose];"(fmMain)");`

When the form it's displayed on the screen, its position is not central, and there is a scroll horizontal on the bottom of it. I don't mind if the scroll exists, but I don't want to be fixed on the middle of the scrollbar, I would like to be in the left part of the scroll-bar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an edit field, dialog list or other editable field which is focused first and is situated in right part of your form.

One way to solve your issue is to rearrange your form so that your first editable field is in lefter part of your form

or

You put on top of your form a new line with left alignment and an editable field. The field should have deselected "Show field delimiters".

Comment: Thanks! Font size 1? Isn't 8 the minimum? I put an empty line but it doesn't work

Comment: Line has to be **left align** and **not hidden**. Yes, in text property box you can write "1" as font size

Comment: and is it the first line in form? The very first on top of form?

Comment: Yes :( I have a table right after the first line but the first line is left align and isn't hidden. Still not works

Comment: Hmm, it does work for me with a table too. Can you show a picture how your document looks like?

Comment: The table margin is Absolute, not Relative (%), is this a problem?

Comment: Well, is a big form .. I think the problem might be on a dialog list field or checkbox ... But there are no fields which have focus... Hmmm, thank you for your help Knut!

Comment: @MFG Flay: You can go down to 1pt in Font Size, but you have to pick a font that supports that. Default Sans Serif only goes down to 8pt, but Arial goes down all the way to 1pt. That is why I always use Arial in my applications...

Comment: @Karl-HenryMartinsson I use "Small Fonts" when I want to go for the 1-pointers.